# Recovering History from Workspace in R

Tags: r

I have lost my R script during system format. But I have a backup of R workspace. Is there a way, I can recover the command that I had used to create the objects in this workspace or history of commands used in that workspace?

Comment: I want the commands not the object values. I know how to load workspace.

Comment: do you have .Rhistory file ?

Comment: No that's what I have lost !! I just have the workSpace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, if you don't have the history or a script, you can't recreate that from the workspace. The saved workspace is just the final state, but there is an infinite number of ways to arrive at this state.